# How to check if a component in angular is shown in the view

Tags: angular

In my angular project I show movie cards with ngFor using a custom tag (app-movie-card). I use a custom pipe in order to filter the movies. When there are no matching movies to the search of the user the view doesn't show any movie card as expected. In this case, how can I show an alternative message like "There are no movies matching your input" using ng-template or something else ?

Thank you !

[Template image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsJSf.jpg)

[Filter pipe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO0Rr.jpg)

Comment: Please do show how you are implementing this. Specifically, things like the function called for the search and your html template.

Comment: I posted photos

Answer (score 0):

You can define some `#elseBlock` (where you put your message about no movies) which you'll show if there are no movies.

so, logic would be:

```
<div *ngIf="moviesCount>0; else elseBlock">
  <div *ngFor=""....
</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>your message here...</ng-template>
```

ref:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else

[UPDATE]

in general, you wouldn't have a pipe for filter/sort. you would either get already sorted/ordered list from your server API or, if you want to sort it on client side, you would have some function inside your component that would do sort/filter on some property.

In your particular example, one approach might be like this: you would have property `movies`. then you would have methods, for example, `filterByType()` and `filterByTitle()`. those methods would take some array and filter condition and as a result, they would assign filtered array to your `movies` properties.
Then, you would bind your `movies` properties to your template without pipes.

First obvious benefit is that then you know the `length` of `movies` (filtered) array right away and you can check if its 0, in which case you show your `<ng-template>...` message part.

Comment: It doesn't work for me because the movies exist and loaded, they are only not shown. The problem is how to detect if they are shown in the view. I tried using a template reference variables but it did not work.

Comment: you've run into just one of the problems of filtering/sorting within pipe. you might want to move filter/order logic to component instead. docs say: "*The Angular team and many experienced Angular developers strongly recommend moving filtering and sorting logic into the component itself.*" ref: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of this issue. How can I move the filter logic into the component using pipes ? Or I nedd to write new code to filter ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The downside of your method is the fact that i need to fetch the movies from the database every time i change the movie type of the search text. Is there a way to filter movies without doing so ?

Comment: you dont have to go to server each time. you can fetch them just once, have it in `moviesRaw` array and then in your filter functions have something like `this.movies=this.moviesRaw.filter(whateverYourFilterConditionIs);` . thats just one, simpliest way.